# What's the difference between gravity="center_vertical" and layout_centerVertical="true"

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-gravity

If I try to center the current view vertically within its parent. Which one should I use?

I saw TextViews use `gravity="center_vertical" and ImageViews use`layout_centerVertical="true".

I am not sure why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `textview` , `gravity="center_vertical"` means the content in the `textview` will be `center` and `vertical` . you can only see the alignment of `text` if `textview` is `fill_parent` if its `wrap_content` then there will be no place for content to have alignment.If you use `layout_gravity` here and width and height to `wrap_content` then it will place the `textview` in the center _vertical of the parent layout.

In `imageview` ,`layout_centerVertical="true".` means place iamge and in `center` and `vertical` in the parent layout of image (i.e the container of image).